# How can I specify the character I want to extract with regex?

Tags: regex

I have links that look something like this:

`https://www.sample.com/sam-i/mel/Vo-20-Jah-Ma-O-lei-da-la-Ede-vn-Clas-Ma-O-ei-45597.html`

The part after .com in the links is always diffrent, but they always end on .html.

I want to extract this part with regex:

`mel/Vo-20-Jah-Ma-O-lei-da-la-Ede-vn-Clas-Ma-O-ei-45597.html`

But with this regex:

`(?:.(?!\/))+$`

I only get this part :

`/Vo-20-Jah-Ma-O-lei-da-la-Ede-vn-Clas-Ma-O-ei-45597.html`

So how can I tell regex to get everything after the penultimate backslash?

Comment: Not clear if you want `sam-i` included (what's the rule of getting `mel...`) - is it the last two sections, or from two sections after `.com`? Try using `(?<!/)(?:/[^/]+)+$`.

Comment: Please review the [`regex` tag info page](/ags/regex/info). You should always specify which regex variant you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By allowing no slashes, then a single slash, then another sequence of characters which are not a slash:

```
[^/]+/[^/]+$
```

The negative lookahead you used would *mostly* work, but is inefficient and unidiomatic. The standard way to say "a character which is not (newline or) one of the following" is a negated character class `[^...]`.

(Those are all slashes, not backslashes {`\\`).)

If in fact you want everything after the third slash, and are using a dialect which permits lookarounds, try

```
(?<=^(?:[^/]*/){3}).*$
```